# Scroll a particular ListView item into view

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

In my application, I have a `ListView`. The data for each item in the list is an instance of the `SomeItem` class. The list has a custom `ArrayAdapter` which has a custom view to display various fields of each items and overrides the `getView()` method. Skeleton code for the initialization of the list view:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) foo.getViewById(R.id.listView);

ArrayAdapter<SomeItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SomeItem>(activity, R.layout.listItemView, R.id.textView) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Code to build the view with multiple child views
    }
}
```

Now assume I have a `SomeItem` instance. Its associated view may or may not be in the portion of the `ListView` which is shown on screen. If it is not, how can I get the `ListView` to scroll this particular item into view?

The only somewhat related method I’ve found is `ListView#requestChildRectangleOnScreen()`, which requires me to provide a child view which I don’t have. I have the item for the adapter. So I’m still not sure how to piece this together. Any pointers?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you show us something that expresses your demand in a pictorial form?

Comment: I’ve edited the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: How will you determine which item needs to be on the screen? What's the logic do you have there?

Comment: There may be different ways of determining that and it’s not 100% definite. However, the decision is made at the level where the list of items is populated, and the code is going to return a `SomeItem` instance. Now I just need to get it to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Calculate the position of the `SomeItem` item you want to make visible. You can do this by iterating over the list of `SomeItem`s that you pass to the adapter.
2. Use `listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()`, `listView.getLastVisiblePosition()` and the calculated position to check if the item is visible on the list.
3. If the item is not visible, make `listView` scroll to it by calling `listView.smoothScrollToPosition(calculatedPosition)`.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising. I’ll upvote; acceptance will follow once I’ve tried it out successfully. Looking at the API, there is `ArrayAdapter#getPosition()` which should return the position so I guess I wouldn’t need an iterator. Also, do I really need to do #2 or is scrolling to an item which is already in view a true no-op (meaning the list will not move at all, as opposed to the item moving to a default position)?

Comment: I don't really remember how `smoothScrollToPosition()` works with an already displayed item - it may cause a little twitch to place it as a top item. Maybe not. Or maybe that's exactly what you want. So try scrolling without *step2* and see if the result satisfies you.

Comment: I tried it briefly: scrolled to the top of the list view, selected the item at the bottom of the screen (the portion on screen being less than half of the list) and waited for the list to fill up. No twitching until new items started pushing the selection off-screen, after which it moved to the bottom of the screen and stayed there. Precisely what I neeed!

Comment: Happy to see that! =)