# Freeze a ListView during sequential updates

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter` to back it. Updates to the list typically involve multiple item add/remove operations, followed by a sort operation. Often, the update just removes one item and adds an almost identical one, which eventually ends up in the same place as the item I removed.

How can I prevent the list view from “twitching” during these operations? Ideally, I would like to freeze all redraw operations, then add, remove and sort items, and only then “unfreeze” the UI, allowing it to be redrawn. Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ArrayAdapter#setNotifyOnChange()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#setNotifyOnChange(boolean)) seems like a candidate for this. Use as follows:

```
myAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
// add, remove and sort items here
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Ensure nothing else in the update code calls `ArrayAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()` (as doing so will trigger a redraw), and updates will be delayed until the transaction is complete.

**EDIT:** after trying this, there is still the occasional twitch, but that may also be caused by the fact that I [scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46595361/2703209) the selected list view item (back) into view after each update.